# angularjs signalr - Resolve server method

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I have some difficulties using SignalR with angularjs (1.5.6)

I use the following libraries:
[Https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub](http://Https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub)

I have the following factory that must support SignalR.

```
'use strict';
app.factory('commonFactory', commonFactory);

commonFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'Hub', '$log'];

function commonFactory($rootScope, Hub, $log) {
    var scope = $rootScope;

    scope.hub = {
        instance : {},
        isReady : false
    };

    var _listeners = {
        'login': function (message) {
            $log.log(message);
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    };
    var _methods = ['connect', 'sendMessage'];

    var _errorHandler = function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    };

    var _hub = new Hub('message', { methods: [] })
    .promise.done(function () {
        _hub.listeners = _listeners;
        _hub.methods = _methods;
        _hub.errorHandler = _errorHandler;

        scope.hub.isReady = true;
        scope.hub.instance = _hub;
    }); 
}
```

In my controller, I use my factory:

```
app.controller('loginController', loginController);

loginController.$inject = ['$scope', 'commonFactory'];

function loginController($scope, commonFactory) {
    $scope.login = _login;


    $scope.model = {
        user : {
            id : 1
        }
    }

    function _login() {
        commonFactory.hub.instance.connect($scope.model.user.id);
    }
}
```

The following line is in error :
commonFactory.hub.instance.connect($scope.model.user.id);

It says :

> commonFactory.hub.instance.connect is not a function

How to resolve server methods (written in c #)

Interface :

```
public interface IMessageHub
{
    [HubMethodName("login")]
    void Login(object message);

    [HubMethodName("send")]
    void Send(object message);

    [HubMethodName("connect")]
    void Connect(Guid userGuid);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixe it with :

> 'use strict';
>
> app.factory('commonFactory', commonFactory);
>
> commonFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'Hub', '$log'];
>
> function commonFactory($rootScope, Hub, $log) {
>       var scope = $rootScope;
>
> var instance = {
>       };
>
> ```
> var hub = new Hub('message', {
>     listeners: {
>         'login': function (from, to, message) {
>           $log.log(message);
>           $rootScope.$apply();;
>         }
>     },
>
>     //server side methods
>     methods: ['connect', 'sendMessage'],
>
>     //handle connection error
>     errorHandler: function (error) {
>         console.error(error);
>     }
> });
>
> var _login = function (userGuid) {
>     hub.promise.done(function () {
>         hub.login(userGuid); //Calling a server method
>     });
> };
>
> instance.login = _login;      return instance; }
> ```